# Meteor: Implement facebook package outside of accounts-facebook

Tags: facebook, meteor, oauth, meteor-accounts

I've got a Meteor application with a multi-phase sign-up process. The accounts are based on the `accounts-password` package. In the step prior to account creation, the user needs to provide some profile information.

I'd like the user to be able to launch a Facebook OAuth flow which pre-populates the profile fields with information pulled from Facebook.

This all needs to happen pre-account-creation. I want to implement this with the `facebook` package that backs `accounts-facebook`.

At the moment I've got the OAuth flow happening by calling `Facebook.requestCredential`, but I'm not sure how to get an OAuth access token from the credential token that comes back. I suspect I need to pass this to the server and make an API call to get back an access token.

Any pointers as to how this should work would be much appreciated.

```
Facebook.requestCredential(function (credentialTokenOrError) {
  if (credentialTokenOrError && credentialTokenOrError instanceof Error) {
    // Error...
    console.log(credentialTokenOrError);
  } else {
    // Credential Token string
    console.log(credentialTokenOrError);
    // Now perhaps a Meteor.call to a server method that
    // 1. Retrieves an access token
    // 2. Hits the graph API to get profile information and returns it to the client
  }
});
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same trouble of converting a `credentialToken` to an `accessToken`, only with Github. I've written up a [gist](https://gist.github.com/sunny-g/87891ac6a0f29cd43636) that has code that should work very similarly. Essentially, there are two steps:

1. Within your `Facebook.requestCredential` callback function, call `OAuth._retrieveCredentialSecret(tokenOrError)`, the result of which is the `credentialSecret`. Then use `Meteor.call`, passing in `tokenOrError` and `credentialSecret`, to call the `Meteor.method` you'll set up in the next step.

code (on client):

```
Github.requestCredential({
  loginStyle: 'popup',
  requestPermissions: ['gist']
}, function(tokenOrError) {
  if (tokenOrError && tokenOrError instanceof Error) {
    // Throw a Meteor error
    console.log('error getting the token');
    return;
  }
  var credentialSecret = OAuth._retrieveCredentialSecret(tokenOrError);
  Meteor.call('getGithubAccessToken', tokenOrError, credentialSecret, function(err, accessToken) {});
});
```

2. On the server, set up a `Meteor.method` that takes your `credentialToken` and `credentialSecret` and calls `Facebook.retrieveCredential`. This function returns a credentials object from the `_pendingCredentials` Mongo Collection before deleting it from the collection. The access token is `credentials.serviceData.accessToken`. The credentials object could potentially be persisted in the user object in the `Meteor.users` collection (as it is in the `accounts` packages) or sent back to the user.

code (on server):

```
  Meteor.methods({
    getGithubAccessToken: function(credentialToken, credentialSecret) {
      var credentials = Github.retrieveCredential(credentialToken, credentialSecret);
      console.log('accessToken:', credentials.serviceData.accessToken);
      return credentials.serviceData.accessToken;
    }
  });
```

I'm unfamiliar with the specifics of Facebook's Graph API so after these steps, you're on your own. Good luck!